# 13.04 Boot from LiveCD into graphical safe mode

Tags: graphics, live-usb, live-cd

I can boot into the livecd without any problems, but to use my machine without it crashing I need to boot it into graphic safe mode and then use the nvidia drivers.

Is it possible to boot into graphical safe mode with the liveCD?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Sure you can just when you have the booting menu of live CD choose the entry xforcevesa-boot with safe mode graphics

Comment: humm i only get 3 options: Try Ubuntu without insalling, install ubuntu, OEM install, check disc for defects! I wish there were another opion